# Excel: Comparing interest rate pricing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to compare the pricing of the rate for a given day with par pricing on that day.

My data has multiple rates and pricing for each given day. I would like to return the pricing value from another worksheet ("WB1")for the interest rate specified in column "A" for a given day in column "C" in my current worksheet ("WB2").

My data in WB1 is custom sorted by Date (Col C), then Rate (Col A)

I have used the following function to find my first rate 9/4/18, but need to do this for 9/5/18, 9/6/18, ...etc.

=INDEX(WB1!$A:$C,MATCH(B1,WB1!$A:$A,0),2)

WB1: Col A = Rate, Col B = Price, Col C = Date

WB2: Col A = Date, Col B = Par Rate, Col C = Par Price, Col D = WB1 Price for Rate on WB2 Date

WB1 Date would be the same date for multiple instances, so finding the associated Price for the Rate given on WB2, only for the date specified on WB2

So I need to search on WB1 Col A (Rate) for the range of rates associated with WB2 Col A (Date)

```
Rate     Pricing      Date               Date    Par Rate    Par Price    Price125
6         102.0       9/4/18       /---> 9/4/18  5           101.75       101.5 
5.5       101.75      9/4/18      /  /-> 9/5/18  4.5         101.5        101.25
5         101.5       9/4/18 <---/  /
4.5       101.25      9/4/18       /
4         101.0       9/4/18      |
3.5       100.75      9/4/18      |
3         100.5       9/4/18      |
6         102.0       9/5/18      |
5.5       101.75      9/5/18      |
5         101.5       9/5/18      |
4.5       101.25      9/5/18 <----/
4         101.0       9/5/18
3.5       100.75      9/5/18
3         100.5       9/5/18
etc       etc         etc
```

[image]

Comment: Add some screenshots of your worksheets, or a table. That visualizes things much better then a description.

Comment: Thanks, This is my first post and didn't know how to put an example table. hopeful the screenshots will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to work around the issue by creating an index column concatenating a combination of the `Month`, `Date`, & `NoteRate` which created a corresponding unique value. From there I used the `Index` & `Match` function below.

`=INDEX(WB1!A:D,MATCH(E1,WB1!D:D,0),2)`

This solved my issue.

```
Rate  Pricing   Date   Index       Date    Par Rate Par Price   Price125 Index
6      102.0    9/4/18 09046.00    9/4/18  5        101.75      101.5    09045.00
5.5    101.75   9/4/18 09045.50    9/5/18  4.5      101.5       101.25   09054.50
5      101.5    9/4/18 09045.00    etc...  etc...   etc...      etc...   
4.5    101.25   9/4/18 09044.50
4      101.0    9/4/18 09044.00
3.5    100.75   9/4/18 09043.50
3      100.5    9/4/18 09043.00
6      102.0    9/5/18 09056.00
5.5    101.75   9/5/18 09055.50
5      101.5    9/5/18 09055.00
4.5    101.25   9/5/18 09054.50
4      101.0    9/5/18 09054.00
3.5    100.75   9/5/18 09053.50
3      100.5    9/5/18 09053.00
etc... etc...   etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an array formula, and assumes your WB2 data:

- G2:= Date
- H2:= Par Rate
- I2:= Par Price
- J2:= Price125

You should be able to move this yourself to WB2 by changing the references.

---

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!$A$1:$C$15,MAX((G2=Sheet3!$C$2:$C$15)*(H2=Sheet3!$A$2:$A$15)*ROW(Sheet3!$A$2:$C$15)),2)
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

I suggest you use the formula evaluation tool to see how this formula works.

Comment: I'm very curious as I couldn't get to understand the problem earlier... Might I ask why the original formula didn't work? `=INDEX(WB1!$A:$C,MATCH(B1,WB1!$A:$A,0),2)` and your formula seems to behave the same. So what detail did I miss :)?

Comment: @Wizhi You are using `MATCH` which will only return a single value.  My formula creates an array of values, but, given the nature of your presented data, only one will match both the DATE and the Rate.  As I wrote, use the Formula Evaluation tool and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for giving some perspective, much appreciated :)!!

Comment: The original equation did not work because there are multiple instances of the same date. The function I posted indexed by Rate, not date. This worked fine for my first date, because for that day the rates were sorted from high to low.

Comment: In order for me to extract the data I need, I would have to parse out all other dates except the specific date I am looking for, then I can index by rate for that range of rates on that day. Unfortunately, the function in the answer did not work either. When I  hold down ctrl + shift while hitting enter I was getting a value that didn't correspond with a rate for that day.

Comment: @EricRavnikar Kindly provide data that reproduces the problem you are seeing, so that I might duplicate it here.  Perhaps by uploading a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some sharing website and posting the link here.